# Como passar uma matriz como referência para uma função?

Tags: c, funções, matriz, parâmetros

Estou tentando passar como parâmetro uma matriz para uma função como referencia, e nesta função fazer operações nessa matriz mas não estou conseguindo. Não quero que use `define` ou `const int` para os valores da dimensão da matriz pois quero que estes valores mudem.

```
    #include <stdio.h>


    int operacao (int *matriz[], int dim){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        for (i=0; i<dim; i++){
            for (j=0; j<dim; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = 1;
                printf("%d,", matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    int main () {
        int dimencao;
        printf ("digite a dimencao da matriz:");
        scanf("%d", &dimencao);
        int matriz[dimencao][dimencao];
        operacao(&matriz,dimencao);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de o fazer é alterando a ordem dos parâmetros para que a dimensão venha antes da matriz, e com isso já consegue usar a dimensão no parâmetro que representa a matriz.

Exemplo:

```
int operacao (int dim, int matriz[dim][dim]) { 
//                |                 ^---^ matriz utiliza o dim do parametro anterior
//                ^ ---- a dimensão agora vem como primeiro parametro
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for (i=0; i<dim; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<dim; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = 1;
            printf("%d,", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    int dimencao;
    printf ("digite a dimencao da matriz:");
    scanf("%d", &dimencao);
    int matriz[dimencao][dimencao];
    operacao(dimencao, matriz); //sem & na matriz, e agora com a ordem invertida
    return 0;
}
```

Alterei apenas as linhas que foram comentadas.

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/HS5Yok)

Answer (score 3):

C é uma linguagem sem muitas abstrações, por isso precisa controlar cada aspecto de forma direta e fazer o que não quer fazer ou criar suas próprias abstrações ou mecanismo para controlar isto.

Você pode passar o tamanho como argumento da função (veja exemplo na resposta do Isac) ou pode criar uma estrutura onde tenha o tamanho e a referência para a matriz, assim passa direto essa estrutura e é nela que vai manipular tudo. De fato esta é a forma mais usada em códigos reais. A forma anterior também é usada em alguns casos mais simples. Eu prefiro a estrutura que é muito flexível, algo assim:

```
typedef {
    size_t size;
    int **matrix;
} Matriz;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/333257/101).

Você terá que fazer a alocação com `malloc()`, mas fora de exercícios quase sempre é o que faria mesmo. É raro criar um um *array* como matriz no *stack* e passar como parâmetro. Se for só exercício faça do jeito mais simples e use um `define`, se não for crie a forma como realmente pode ser usada universalmente.

Essa forma que você não quer usar só é usada em exercícios. Boa parte de tudo o que encontrará na internet, em livros e na maioria das fontes é só código de exercício, não é como realmente se programa. Mas a maioria das pessoas não vão programar em C de verdade.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, a sua e a do Isac me ajudaram a resolver o problema.